# MySQL dynamic order by works different than static

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a stored procedure that behaves differently depending upon how the order by clause is set.

When I set `order by` as static using the `compliance` field:

```
select id
    , compliance
    , rolling
    , last_date
        , oldest_date
from table
order by compliance asc
```

works and sorts by `compliance` as a `number`.  If I try to make it dynamic:

```
select id
    , compliance
    , rolling
    , last_date
    , oldest_date
from table
order by 
    CASE WHEN prm_sort = 'last_date' THEN last_date
                WHEN prm_sort = 'oldest_date' THEN oldest_date
                WHEN prm_sort = 'rolling' THEN rolling
                WHEN prm_sort = 'compliance' THEN compliance
            END ASC
```

It sorts the `compliance` field as a `string`.  When using the dynamic approach with the other fields, it sorts as expected.

Why would the sort behave differently for the `compliance` field (as per example) and how do I get it to work consistently?

Comment: CASE returns the most common datatype. For DATE (1st and 2nd) and some numeric (3rd and 4th) datatypes this is string datatype, without variants.

Comment: @Akina So how do I get it to sort as a number?  I have used cast without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `last_date` and `oldest_date` columns have some datetime datatypes, and `rolling` and `compliance` are numeric, use:

```sql
ORDER BY
-- firstly divide sorting expression to groups with the same datatype
         CASE WHEN prm_sort IN ('last_date', 'oldest_date') 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 2
              END,
-- sort first group which produces datetime datatype, 
-- use datetime constant for another group
         CASE WHEN prm_sort = 'last_date' THEN last_date
              WHEN prm_sort = 'oldest_date' THEN oldest_date
              ELSE CURRENT_DATE
              END,
-- sort another group which produces numeric datatype
-- use numeric constant for first group
         CASE WHEN prm_sort = 'rolling' THEN rolling
              WHEN prm_sort = 'compliance' THEN compliance
              ELSE 0
              END
```